# Removing Ghidra auto-generated labels and create function. Overlapping namespace error

Tags: ghidra, java, script

I am attempting to write a script to parse a function table containing structs that look like this:

```c
struct func_table_entry {
    void (* func)(void *);
    byte unknown1;
    byte unknown2;
    byte unknown3;
    char * func_name;
};
```

I made a script already to define the stucts, but I am having trouble cleaning up the automatic analysis Ghidra does. I have fixed func_name where sometimes Ghidra thinks that the strings are code. I want to  define the functions pointed to by `func`.

Most of the time this works, but sometimes I get an error:

```java
Function newFunction = functionManager.createFunction(func_string, funcAddress_real, new AddressSet(funcAddress_real), SourceType.USER_DEFINED);
```

The error:

```
ghidra.program.database.function.OverlappingFunctionException: Unable to create function at 0113c4e due to overlap with another namespace
```

So the question ultimately is that if there is already something labeled "LAB_WXYZ" how do I remove that and define my own function.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off auto analysis options before running script. This gets in the way as it reacts to changes